# what happens to the pixels andRGB when image resizing?

Tags: rgb, pixel, image-resizing

How does image resize[Adding and Reducing size of image] works and what happens to the pixels and RGB ?
explain briefly

Comment: This seems a school assignment. In any case: What did you look? What do you know about resizing? What are your problems?

Answer (score 1):

An RGB image has three channels: red, green, and blue. RGB channels roughly follow the color receptors in the human eye, and are used in computer displays and image scanners.

If the RGB image is 24-bit (the industry standard as of 2005), each channel has 8 bits, for red, green, and blue—in other words, the image is composed of three images (one for each channel), where each image can store discrete pixels with conventional brightness intensities between 0 and 255. If the RGB image is 48-bit (very high color-depth), each channel is made of 16-bit images.

Image interpolation occurs when you resize or distort your image from one pixel grid to another. Image resizing is necessary when you need to increase or decrease the total number of pixels, whereas remapping can occur when you are correcting for lens distortion or rotating an image. Zooming refers to increase the quantity of pixels, so that when you zoom an image, you will see more detail.

So the number of pixels will be reduced which means it will have a less rgb pixels.